# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] with using itemize in longtable

Tags: errors, longtable, itemize

I didn't use LaTeX for the past two years and now I want to use it again, so I downloaded TexLive and Texmaker and istalled them. Now I have tried to open and compile one of my old dokuments. I had to change some packages and also tried some fixes but the last problem I can't fix and I don't know what to do anymore...
So maybe one of you can help me :)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside, parskip]{scrreprt}

% UTF8 Encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

% Schriftart
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% Zeichensatz mit Umlauten
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,lmodern}

% Tabellen
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\mcr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[0]{{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}l}

%Aufzählung
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Kopf- & Fußzeile
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l|L|L}
\toprule
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Aussehen} & \textbf{Eigenschaften}\\
\midrule

\textbf{Elisabeth Jung} &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item schlank
\item schulterlanges braunes Haar
\item eisblaue Augen
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item stur
\end{itemize}\\
\hline

\textbf{Kriminalhauptkommissar Bernd Steiger} &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item s
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item s
\end{itemize}\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you sure this ever worked?

Comment: `\newcolumntype{L}[0]{{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}l}` can never have worked Hard to guess what was intended but if you change it to `\newcolumntype{L}{p{5cm}}` it will at least make a valid table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that `\newcolumntype{L}[0]{{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}l}` successful at all in earlier times.

I've changed the `L` columntype to a standard type

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}

\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\raggedright\bfseries}p{#1}}
```

and provided `B` as **Bold** column type for the first column.

Please note that the several `\item` do not appear on the same line in general.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside, parskip]{scrreprt}

% UTF8 Encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

% Schriftart
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% Zeichensatz mit Umlauten
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,lmodern}

% Tabellen
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\mcr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}

\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\raggedright\bfseries}p{#1}}

%\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}

%Aufzählung
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Kopf- & Fußzeile
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{B{6cm}|*{2}{L{5cm}|}}
  Name & \textbf{Aussehen} & \textbf{Eigenschaften}\tabularnewline
Elisabeth Jung &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item schlank
\item schulterlanges braunes Haar
\item eisblaue Augen
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item stur
\end{itemize}\tabularnewline

Kriminalhauptkommissar Bernd Steiger &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item s
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item s
\end{itemize}


\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]